# elements that are present in pandas dataframe col, the column is in list format other column has single element (relationship query)

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {
        'id' :[2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
        'idlist': [[2,33],[3,3],[4,73],[5,20],[6,41],[7,41,73,44,10,32,11,31,20,74,17,69,8,16,23,43,72,70,7],[9,9],[10,10,68],[11,11,11],[12,24],[13,20],[14,20],[17,17,68],[18,18],[19,33],[20,20,21,36,40],[21,21],[22,41],[23,23,56,],[24,33,24,]]

        }

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x['id'] in x['idlist']), axis=1)

df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: int( x['idlist'] in x['id']), axis=1) --- error when i try to  find a list of elements in the idlist to the id column...
```

TypeError: ("argument of type 'int' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')

Dataframe_output original
    id  idlist
    2   [2, 33]
    3   [3, 3]
    4   [4, 73]
    5   [5, 20]
    6   [6, 41]
    7   [7, 41, 73, 44, 10, 32, 11, 31, 20, 74, 17, 69, 8, 16, 23, 43, 72, 70, 7]
    9   [9, 9]
    10  [10, 10, 68]
    ...
    20  20,20,21,36,40,

Need to find the idlist elements is there in the id column

for example 20 in 5th row is present in 20 the

edited dataframe
data = {
        'id' :[2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
        'idlist':[[33],[3],[73],[20],[41],[41,73,44,10,32,11,31,20,74,17,69,8,16,23,43,72,70],[9],[68],[111],[24],[11,20],[2,20],[3,68],[188],[33],[21,36,40],[3],[41,3],[56],[33,]]

```
    }
```

[refered this link][1]
jezrael  - answer and tried the other way round but getting an error,

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: int( x['idlist'] in x['id']), axis=1)
```

TypeError: ("argument of type 'int' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')

output dataframe

```
   id   idlist  foundlist
2   [33]    
4   [73]    
5   [20]    [20]
6   [41]    
7   [41, 73, 44, 10, 32, 11, 31, 20, 74, 17, 69, 8, 16, 23, 43, 72, 70] [10,11,20,17]
10  [68]    
11  [111]   
12  [24]    
13  [11, 20]    [11]
14  [2, 20] [2,20]
17  [3, 68] [3]
18  [188]   
19  [33]    
20  [21, 36, 40]
```

Comment: Just so I get it right, you want to check, if every id in each idlist is in the id column?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: Not sure if understand, your solution means find if `[2, 33]` is in `2`, so have no sense. Can you explian more, what do you need?

Comment: I have edited the dataframe idlist

Comment: I have edited the dataframe idlist, one more edit to the dataframe idlist as the self ids are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 45)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 150)

data = {
    'id': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    'idlist': [[2, 33], [3, 3], [4, 73], [5, 20], [6, 41],
               [7, 41, 73, 44, 10, 32, 11, 31, 20, 74, 17, 69, 8, 16, 23, 43, 72, 70, 7], [9, 9], [10, 10, 68],
               [11, 11, 11], [12, 24], [13, 20], [14, 20], [17, 17, 68], [18, 18], [19, 33], [20, 20, 21, 36, 40],
               [21, 21], [22, 41], [23, 23, 56, ], [24, 33, 24, ]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


df['flag'] = df['idlist'].apply(lambda el: [x for x in el if x in list(df.id) ])

df



    id                idlist          flag
0    2               [2, 33]           [2]
1    3                [3, 3]        [3, 3]
2    4               [4, 73]           [4]
3    5               [5, 20]       [5, 20]
4    6               [6, 41]           [6]
..  ..                   ...           ...
15  20  [20, 20, 21, 36, 40]  [20, 20, 21]
16  21              [21, 21]      [21, 21]
17  22              [22, 41]          [22]
18  23          [23, 23, 56]      [23, 23]
19  24          [24, 33, 24]      [24, 24]
```

Comment: can I get the element number/name after I flag 1 in another column, (name of the element present)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Do you want the element itself or the index position inside the list ? if you could also write your expected output that would help a lot

Comment: I want the element itself, (value)

Comment: what if my idlist doesn't have the [ ] list or square brackets or how to add square [ ] to the column idlist in pandas dataframe

Comment: df['col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)

Comment: I am getting empty dataframe, any idea

Comment: df_test.dtypes
Out[60]: 
id     int64
idlist      object
dtype: object

Comment: 0                  2         [2,33]   []
1                  3          [3,3]   []
2                  4         [4,73]   []
3                  5         [5,20]   []

Comment: my id list is in this fashions idlist
idlist
Out[166]: 
['[2,33]',
 '[3,3]',
 '[4,73]',]  or  idlist
Out[176]: 
['2,33',
 '3,3',
 '4,73',]

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham I think you need to post a new question

Comment: df['idlist'] = df['idlist'].str.replace(',',' ').str.split()
df['label'] =  df['label'].astype(str)  This could work if you have some problem with your string

Answer (score 2):

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: int( x['idlist'] in x['id']), axis=1) --- error when i try to  find a list of elements in the idlist to the id column..
```

If you want to check

if an int in de 'idlist' column is present in the 'id' column, of the same row?

It's the same as the other way around

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x['id'] in x['idlist']), axis=1)
```

The first option gives you an error because x['id'] returns an int instead of an list object like  x['idlist']. An int is not iterable

If you want to check any of the x['idlist'] of a row against the whole column id's you can

```
df['flag'] =    df.apply(lambda x: int( any(x['idlist'])  in  df['id']), axis=1)
```

See the difference? You evaluate **x** (on a row level) against the whole column id (**df**).

Comment: I also need the flag id from the id list

Comment: df['idlist'] = df['idlist'].str.replace(',',' ').str.split()
df['label'] =  df['label'].astype(str)  This could work if you have some problem with your string